# How to make a Google Line Chart reference element values instead of static numbers

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization

I am currently attempting to design a Google Chart which is modelled based on values within certain div tags throughout a html document.

as it stands, there are a number of tags throughout the document such as:

```
<div id="abc"> 11000 </div>
<div id="def"> 12500 </div>
<div id="ghi"> 17000 </div>
```

I would like the Google Chart to reference these values as the Y-axis.

The Google Charts code works fine like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Age', 'Current', 'Proposed'],
          ['25',  10000],
          ['35',  15170],
          ['45',  21660],
        ]);
        var options = {
          title: 'Balance Comparison',
          curveType: 'function',
          legend: { position: 'bottom' }
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
 <div id="curve_chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
```

I would like to change the array in such a way that references the div values. I attempted to do this, and ended up with this:

```
function drawChart() {
            var y1 = document.getElementByID("abc")
            var y2 = document.getElementByID("def")
            var y3 = document.getElementByID("ghi")
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
              ['Age', 'Current'],
              ['25',  y1],
              ['35',  y2],
              ['45',  y3],
            ]);
```

This does not seem to work however, and I am at a loss as to how to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

it will work, first, a couple things...

javascript is case sensitive, change `getElementByID` to `getElementById` (note the last letter)

`getElementById` gets the element, but you want the contents of the element.
use `innerHTML` to get the contents.

```
var y1 = document.getElementById('abc').innerHTML;
```

finally, google charts expects a number for the y value,
`innerHTML` returns a string.

use `parseFloat` to convert the string to a number.

```
parseFloat(y1)
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var y1 = document.getElementById('abc').innerHTML;
  var y2 = document.getElementById('def').innerHTML;
  var y3 = document.getElementById('ghi').innerHTML;

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Age', 'Current'],
    ['25',  parseFloat(y1)],
    ['35',  parseFloat(y2)],
    ['45',  parseFloat(y3)],
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Balance Comparison',
    curveType: 'function',
    legend: { position: 'bottom' }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="abc"> 11000 </div>
<div id="def"> 12500 </div>
<div id="ghi"> 17000 </div>
<div id="curve_chart"></div>
```